# Big query filter on Date condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am new to GCP. I am working in Covid 19 data set and wanted to filter the data based on year of date or month of the year. I have used year(date) = '2020' in other rdbms and was able to filter the date. However I am unable to do the same is bigquery.
Below is the query that I am using.

```
SELECT 
extract (year from date) as Affected_year,
extract (month from date) as Affected_Month, 
(sum(deaths_white)/sum(cases_white))*100 As White_Death_Percent, 
(sum(deaths_black)/sum(cases_black)) *100 As Black_Death_Percent, 
(sum(deaths_asian)/sum(cases_asian)) *100 As Asian_Death_Percent, 
(sum(deaths_latinx)/sum(cases_latinx)) *100 As Latin_Death_Percent, 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.covid19_tracking.covid_racial_data_tracker` 
WHERE year(date) = '2021'
Group by Affected_year, Affected_Month
order by Affected_year, Affected_Month ;
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: BigQuery doesn't support `YEAR()` function. Use `EXTRACT(year from date)` same as you used in `SELECT` list instead.   `EXTRACT(year from date) = 2021`

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I tried using extract function in where clause earlier but with quotes for '2021', which was throwing error.